# How to generate properties version for dependency/plugin?

Tags: maven

I'm looking for a maven plugin that generate dynamically version variable of a dependency or plugin under properties tag. It will need to generate a `pom.xml` with these changes.

For example

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
   <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

need to became

```
 <properties>
   <plexus-archiver.version>2.2</plexus-archiver.version>
 </properties>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
    <version>${plexus-archiver.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

This is possible to do it manually, but when you have many many dependencies it can become redundant.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. You can replace the one snippet with the other without any plugin. Are you looking for a plugin to dynamically set the version based on some logic? Please update your question to explain what exactly you need to do, what have you tried and what problem(s) you've faced.

Comment: I apologize if it wasn't clear, I edited my post.

Comment: I have done this manually for a lot of properties ... I have never seen a plugin for this.

Comment: I think you should explain the use case and/or provide an example. You say you want to "generate a pom.xml" which suggest an external tool needs to do it beforehand. But you also state that you are "looking for a maven plugin" which indicates you want to dynamically modify existing POM at the execution time. It is also not clear where the actual versions would come from regardless what the strategy is.